# Fundamental group of the plane with infinite puncture

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to calculate the Fundamental Group of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Z}^2$.

I know that the Fundamental group of the Plane with $k$ punctures is the free product of $k$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. My guess is that $\pi (\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Z}^2)$ will be the free product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. But I could not prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. The standard 'pushing away from the holes' idea gives you that this space is homotopically equivalent to an "infinite grid" (the union of all lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $y = n$ or $x = m$ for integers $n, m$). The $\pi_1$ of this is certainly gonna be free (it's a connected graph, so we take a maximal subtree and collapse). This graph only has countably many edges, so the $\pi_1$ is free on at most countably generators, and the maximal tree surely must miss infinitely many edges (every square on the grid gives a cycle, so at least one edge in each square needs to get removed), so this $\pi_1$ is free on (countably) infinitely many generators.

Comment: Just a remark: one example of a maximal subtree in this grid would be all lines $x=m$ together with $y=0$.